# Как динамически изменять язык в React используя i18n?

Tags: reactjs, i18n

Делаю возможность изменения языка на сайте используя i18n.

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'

i18n
  // Подключение бэкенда i18next
  .use(Backend)
  // Автоматическое определение языка 
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // модуль инициализации
  .use (initReactI18next)
  .init({
    // Стандартный язык
    fallbackLng: 'ru',
    debug: true,
    // Распознавание и кэширование языковых кук
    detection: {
      order: ['queryString', 'cookie'],
      cache: ['cookie']
    },
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  })

export default i18n;
```

по клику изменяю языки

```
 const changeLanguage = (language) => {
  i18n.changeLanguage(language);
};
```

в запросе на сервер динамически меняю язык

```
export const fetchReservoirs = async () => {
const {data} = await axios.get('.../api/general/menu/reservoirs', {
    headers: {
      'language': i18n.language
    }
})
return data
}
```

Все работает, перевод есть. Только вот он появляется только если обновить страницу, ну или будет сделан новый запрос на сервер.
Как можно сделать так, чтобы данные менялась без перезагрузки страницы?